# Jackson fails to deserialize Kotlin data classes

Tags: jackson, kotlin, proguard

I'm using Jackson to deserialize Kotlin data classes. I'm using the `jackson-kotlin-module` but Jackson is giving me the following error:

> Can not construct instance of MyClass: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value

I've tried adding proguard rules to keep my classes, and it's constructor without any success.

If I add a rule to keep all kotlin classes the error goes away.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your question did not have enough information for others to solve the issue, not showing code example or Proguard configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I discovered that Proguard was stripping `kotlin.Metadata` annotations from my data classes.

Adding the following rule fixes the issue:

```
-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }
```

I also found adding a rule to keep synthetic methods on my data classes was needed too:

```
-keepclassmembers public class com.mypackage.** {
    public synthetic <methods>;
}
```

Comment: Which build tool do you use (gradle/maven)? Where did you add these rules?